# Не могу понять, почему при записи в сокет epoll_wait выдает -1, а не кол во дескрипторов готовых для чтения/записи

Tags: c++, сервер, websocket, unix, epoll

Пишу свой WS сервер на с++, для выполнения задачи потребовалось использовать epoll. Для теста я написал код, который в одном потоке слушает порт и при поступлении нового соединения заносит его дескриптор в список epoll, а в другом вызывается epoll_wait и читаeт данные из дескрипторов, которые epoll_wait вернул. Но, похоже, я что то сделал неправильно, т.к epoll_wait всегда возвращает -1 (errno = 14). Помогите найти ошибку

Сначала думал, что ошибка в том, что дескриптор блокирующий, попробовал без EPOLLET, результат тот же.

```
int main()
{
    int epfd = epoll_create(100); // создаю пул потоков
    int server_d = create_socket("8001"); // создаю сервер
    if(server_d < 0)
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "error create socket\n");
      return -1;
    }
    printf("WS server created!\n");
    std::thread th_test([&]()  // в отдельном потоке слушаю порт, и при появлении новых соединений заношу их в пул потоков epoll
    {
        while (1)
        {

            int client_d =  create_client(server_d); // эта функция слушает порт, и когда поступает соединение открывает клиентский дескриптор
            epoll_event ev;
            ev.events = EPOLLIN | EPOLLET;
            ev.data.fd = client_d;
            int res = epoll_ctl(epfd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, client_d, &ev); //заношу новый клиентский дескриптор в список потоков
            if (res < 0)
                continue;
            char* request = get_request(client_d); // читаю с сокета запрос на соединение
            char* key = parse_WS_key(request); // из запроса узнаю ключи, для создания соединения
            if (key == NULL)
            {
                close(client_d);
                free(request);
                continue ;
            }
            send_WS_open_header(client_d, key); // отправляю http сообщение, открывающее соккет
            free(request);
            free(key);

        }

    });
    th_test.detach();

    while (1) {
        epoll_event* events;
        int ev_size = epoll_wait(epfd, events, 100, -1); // ждем пока в один из дескрипторов будет что то записано
        int g = errno;
        for (int i = 0; i < ev_size; i++)
        {
            int opcode, fin;
            int fd = events[i].data.fd;
            char* data = WSrecv(fd, &opcode, &fin); // читаем пришедшее сообщение
            printf("%s \n", data);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если открыть документацию (например, эту https://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=epoll_wait&category=2&russian=0) то там написано, что функция `epoll_wait` возвратит `-1` в случае ошибки. Смотрим в код и находим ошибку.

```cpp
epoll_event* events; // а указатель то неинициализированный!!!
int ev_size = epoll_wait(epfd, events, 100, -1);  // и функции теперь что делать?
```

Правильный способ

```cpp
epoll_event events;
int ev_size = epoll_wait(epfd, &events, 100, -1);
```

Другие ошибки не исключены:)